# How is the symbol error rate for M-QAM, 4QAM,16QAM and 32QAM derived?

Tags: modulation, amplitude

How do you derive the theoretical symbol error rate as a function of $E_\mathrm{b}/N_0$ for 4QAM? I know that the result should be $Q\left(\sqrt{2E_\mathrm{b}/N_0}\right)$ but I am ĺooking for the derivation. Also, what are the symbol error rates vs $E_\mathrm{b}/N_0$ for 16QAM and 32QAM?

Comment: Homework, or do you need it for a particular reason?

Comment: I am studying for an exam but I can't find this information in textbooks

Comment: The theoretical **symbol** error rate for 4-QAM is **not** $Q(\sqrt{2E_b/N_0})$; that's the **bit** error rate. The $2$-bit 4-QAM **symbol** can have _zero_ or _one_ or _two_ bit errors in it, and the probability that the **symbol** is in error is not the same as the probability that a bit is in error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In $2^{2n}$-QAM with a square constellation, there are $4$ "corner" points and
$4(2^n-2)$ "edge" points, and $(2^n-2)^2$ "interior" points.  The *conditional*
symbol error probabilities given that each type of point is transmitted,
are
$$\begin{align}
P_e(\text{corner}) &= 2Q(x) - Q^2(x)\\
P_e(\text{edge}) &= 3Q(x) - 2Q^2(x)\\
P_e(\text{interior}) &= 4Q(x) - 4Q^2(x)\\
\end{align}$$
where $Q(x)$ is the complementary cumulative probability distribution function
of the standard Gaussian random variable. Combining these using the law of
total probability (with the assumption that all $2^{2n}$ signals are equally
likely) gives
$$P_e\left(2^{2n}\text{-QAM}\right) = 4 \left[1 - 2^{-n}\right]Q(x) 
- 4\left[1 - 2^{-n}\right]^2Q^2(x)$$
For $4$-QAM, where $n = 1$ and all the constellation points are corner points, this reduces to
$P_e(4\text{-QAM}) = 2Q(x) - Q^2(x)$.

---

**(This added part is for those who like to cross their eyes and dot their teas)**

So where do the above formulas come from? Well, for corner points, a symbol error occurs if the transmitted corner point is mistaken for either of its two nearest (edge) neighbors (or for other constellation points even farther away than the nearest neighbor). These *independent* events have probability $Q(x)$ each, and using $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B),$$ we get
$$P_e(\text{corner}) = 2Q(x) - Q^2(x).$$ An edge point has three nearest neighbors, two of which are either corner points or edge points and one of which is an interior point. Now we use
$$\require{cancel}P(A\cup B\cup C)= P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-\cancelto{0}{P(A\cap C)}-P(B\cap C) + \cancelto{o}{P(A\cap B\cap C)}$$ and independence of $A,B$ and of $B,C$ to get
$$P_e(\text{edge}) = 3Q(x) - 2Q^2(x).$$
Finally, an interior point has four nearest neighbors, the events "symbol error in the I direction" and "symbol error in the Q direction" are independent events of probability $2Q(x)$ each, and so
$$P_e(\text{interior}) = 4Q(x) - 4Q^2(x).$$

Comment: For the corner points, there are 2 nearest neighbours and one farther (sqrt(2) times far as the nearest one). In your answer you disregard the probability that the corner point may end up at this farther point, but it can, which is why for an accurate answer i believe this should be factored in as well

Comment: @AnirudhRoy See revised wording. The result that I have stated is correct; if you feel you are right and something needs to be corrected, please write your own answer with what you believe are the correct formulas.