# The error probability of 16QAM

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, homework, snr

The signal constellation for a communication system with 16 equiprobable symbols is shown as below. The channel is AWGN with noise power spectral density of $N_ 0/2.$Using the union bound, ﬁnd a bound in terms of $A$ and $N_0$ on the error probability for this channel.

[image]

Does the union bound means error probability?the solution said
$$P_e \le 15Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{min}}{2N_0}}\right)=15Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{2A^2}{N_0}}\right)
$$

but why is

\begin{align}
&2\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+2\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)\\
&+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+4\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+4\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)\\
&+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+4\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+4\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)\\
&+2\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+3\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)+2\cdot\frac{1}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)\\
&=\frac{48}{16}Q\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{\frac{N_0}{2}}}\right)\quad{?}
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the symbol error probability is given by

$$P_E=\sum_{i=1}^MP[s_i]P[E|s_i]\tag{1}$$

where $P[s_i]$ is the probability that symbol $s_i$ was sent, $P[E|s_i]$ is the error probability given that $s_i$ was sent, and $M$ is the number of symbols. If all symbols are equally likely, $(1)$ simplifies to

$$P_E=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^MP[E|s_i]\tag{2}$$

For $16$-QAM it is possible to derive an exact expression for the error probabilities $P[E|s_i]$ (and hence for the symbol error probability $P_E$). You can find the derivation in most digital communication text books. A good approximation (better than the union bound) is given in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16254/4298).

The union bound approximation gives an upper bound on $P[E|s_i]$:

$$P[E|s_i]\le\sum_{j\neq i}P[s_j\text{ chosen}|s_i\text{ sent}]\tag{3}$$

Under the given assumptions we have

$$P[s_j\text{ chosen}|s_i\text{ sent}]=Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{ij}}{2N_0}}\right)\tag{4}$$

where $d_{ij}$ is the distance between symbols $s_i$ and $s_j$. With $(3)$ and $(4)$ the union bound approximation of $(2)$ becomes

$$P_E\le\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M\sum_{j\neq i}Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{ij}}{2N_0}}\right)\tag{5}$$

Note that generally you will get a sum of $Q$ functions with *different* arguments because the distances $d_{ij}$ are usually not all the same. This is also the case for $16$-QAM.

The solution you provided is still more conservative (hence, worse) than the union bound. That solution uses the fact that the $Q$ function is monotonically decreasing, which implies

$$Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{ij}}{2N_0}}\right)\le Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{min}}{2N_0}}\right)\tag{6}$$

with $d_{min}=\min_{i\neq j}\{d_{ij}\}$ being the smallest occurring distance between symbols. Plugging $(6)$ into $(5)$ we finally get the bound

$$P_E\le (M-1)Q\left(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{min}}{2N_0}}\right)\tag{7}$$

which, as mentioned above, is even less tight than the union bound.

Comment: so union bound is one of method of calculating the error probability,and better than mine,but do you have the proof about $P_e \le (M-1)Q(\sqrt{\frac{d^2_{min}}{2N_0}})$ ?

Comment: Is Eq. (7) a definition?if not,it must have a proof,because i don't understand why  the enominator in Q function is $2N_0$,not $\frac{N_0}{2}$

Comment: @ShineSun: The noise variance is indeed $N_0/2$, and the argument of the $Q$ function must be *half* the distance between the symbols divided by the square root of the noise variance: $\frac{d/2}{\sqrt{N_0/2}}=\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{2N_0}}$

Comment: ok! now i think my problem is (M-1),because the difference of union bound and mine is the value before Q function.How does (M-1) come from?

Comment: @ShineSun: Just plug (6) into (5) and note that the sum $\sum_{j\neq i}$ is over $M-1$ equal numbers.

Comment: @ShineSun: If this answer helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: don't understand,but there is also a $\frac{1}{M} \sum ^M_{i=1}$ in (5)

Comment: @ShineSun: Yes, there is. It's a sum over $M$ equal elements that's divided by $M$. What do you get if you sum up $M$ equal numbers and divide the result by $M$?

Comment: you mean $\frac{M}{M}$=$1$?

Comment: @ShineSun: Yes, that's what I mean.