# What's the minimum nearest neighbour approximation of this?

Tags: snr

What's the minimum nearest neighbour approximation and upper approximation of this?

Consider a modulation design with the signal space diagram illustrated in
the figure below. The signals are transmitted over an AWGN channel with
power spectral density $ N_0/2 = 5 × 10^{−6}$. The maximum signal energy is $25 × 10^{−4}$. We assume that all the signals are equally probable.

[image]

*suppose each grid has a length of d.*

Nearest Neighbour approximation

The minimum distamce $d_{min} = 2d$

There are 8 of this pair who has only one nearest neighbor

[image].

$$8 Q(\frac{2 d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}})$$

[image]

There are 4 points which has two minimum distance $2 d$.

$$8 Q(\frac{2 d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}})$$

$$P_e = \frac{1} {16} \biggl(8 \times 1 Q(\frac{2 d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) + 4 \times 2 Q(\frac{2  d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}) \biggl)$$

Am I right? Can anyone give me a confirmation?

Comment: I'd recommend using the union bound for this problem.

Comment: @MBaz How do you calculate union bounds? Any hints?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/45748/11256

Comment: @MBaz The link your provided gave me only dull formulas. But the question here is on how to use the formula. And how to draw boundaries and diagram>

Comment: Very good! Thank-you.

Comment: @kile Your formula is correct -- it is a correct approximation to $P_e$ that is tight for large SNR.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really my area, but I think your update missed out four points with a minimum distance of $2\sqrt{2} d$ in blue below:

[image: Annotated signal constellation]

So I think the original equation is better:

$$P_e = \frac{1} {16} \left(\color{red}{8 \times 1 Q\left(\frac{2 d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}\right)} + \color{blue}{4 \times 1 Q\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2} d} {\sqrt{2 N_0}}\right)} + \color{green}{4\times 2  Q\left(\frac{2 d}{\sqrt{2 N_0}}\right)} \right)$$

[I'm going by this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btfOiuUXV-c)

Comparing the two, they do appear to be quite close.

[image: Comparison]

---

### Code Only Below

```matlab
No = logspace(-10,0,1000);
Pe1 = 1/16*(8*qfunc(2*d./sqrt(2*No)) + 8*qfunc(2*d./sqrt(2*No)))
Pe2 = 1/16*(8*qfunc(2*d./sqrt(2*No)) + 4*qfunc(2*sqrt(2)*d./sqrt(2*No)) + 8*qfunc(2*d./sqrt(2*No)))

plot(No, Pe1)
hold on;
plot(No, Pe2)
hold off;
```

Comment: since $d_{min} = 2d$, I don't think we should include those points who has distance greater than $2d$.

Comment: @kile Understood! You might be right.  As I said, not really my area. What I did might be the union bound, not the minimum nearest neighbor.

Comment: The usual, high-SNR approximation includes only those points at the constellation's minimum distance, sacrificing accuracy for simplicity. Including points at distances larger than $d_\text{min} = 2d$ makes the approximation a little bit more accurate, especially for lower SNR. In fact, including points at _all_ distances makes the formula exact!

Comment: The _second nearest_ neighbors of the 4 corner points of the central (green) square are not the ones that you have used (inner ends of blue lines) but the inner ends of the red lines, which are at distance $\sqrt{5}d$ instead of $\sqrt{8}d$.